# Como posso checar se uma string contém outra em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

Gostaria de checar se uma string contém outra, como se fosse um método `String.contains()` mas aparentemente não existe nenhum método que faça isso.

Alguém conheçe um método parecido que faça a mesma coisa?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Utilize a função [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
var s = "foo";
alert(s.indexOf("oo") != -1);
```

A função `indexOf` retorna a posição de uma string em outra string ou -1 se não encontrar.

Comment: exatamente o que eu estava procurando.

Answer (score 12):

Usando um regex é possivel saber se determinado texto está contido em outro, usando metodo `match()`. Sua regex deve ser delimitada por `//`

[modificadores em js](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

[lista de metacaracteres](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/metacaracteres.html)

```
var str = 'algum texto';
if(str.match(/texto/)){
  alert('string encontrada');
}
```

Comment: E se eu quisesse encontrar mais de uma palavra em uma frase? Exemplo: Algum texto aqui quero saber se existem as palavras "texto" ou "Aqui", tem como?

Answer (score 5):

Também é possível encontrar string dentro de outra através do método **[includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)**:

```js
let string = 'Meu texto aqui';
let result = string.includes('texto');

console.log(result);
```

O que é muito útil se for utilizado com o método [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) por exemplo:

```js
let string = 'Tamanho 12,12cm';
let array = string.split(' ');

let filtro = array.filter(valor => valor.includes(','))

console.log(filtro);    // em forma de array
console.log(String(filtro));   // em forma de string
```