# Validar um link no input

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validation-engine

Boas pessoal, eu queria fazer um formulário em que num input é obrigatório meter um link da Steam.
Como faço?
Obrigado.

Comment: Meter, que contexto hahaha. Já tentou usar pattern do HMTL5? Qual o tipo de link que você quer validar da steam? Existem vários. Exemplo: O link do perfil do usuário?

Comment: Já usei pattern, link do perfil

Comment: Porque você não pede apenas o id do usuário e você mesmo monta o link, visto que é um link padrão? Ficaria bem mais prático do que deixar essa dependência na mão de quem for se cadastrar nesse formulário.

Comment: Como assim? como monto o link?

Comment: Cada pessoa tem um link Steam especifico

Comment: Meu link da stem: http://steamcommunity.com/id/damondudek2
Meu outro link: http://steamcommunity.com/id/damondudek1
Viu o que muda é apenas o id?
Basta no seu formulário, ter o campo ID Steam.
Você montaria o link:
http://steamcommunity.com/id/ + "Valor do input"

Comment: Mas em alguns casos o link da steam é assim  : http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/78125979852/

Answer (score 1):

Pela tag [jquery-validation-engine](/questions/tagged/jquery-validation-engine) presumo que esteja usando o plguin jquery `jquery.validationEngine.js`, se for isso mesmo então primeiro baixe os arquivos em https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine (se necessário).

Se o campo for obrigatório:

```
class="validate[required,custom[url]] text-input"
```

Se o campo for opcional:

```
class="validate[custom[url]] text-input"
```

O uso deve ser algo como:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-pt-br.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#meuFormulario").validationEngine();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="meuFormulario" class="formular" method="post">
        <label>
            <span>Field is optional : </span>
            <input value="" class="validate[custom[url]] text-input" type="text" name="optional" id="optional" />
        </label>
        <button>Enviar</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Agora se quer checar de fato se o link é da Steam, você pode criar o seu proprio validador, por exemplo no HTML faça algo como:

```
 <input value="" class="validate[required,funcCall[checarLinkSteam]] text-input" type="text" id="linksteam" name="linksteam" />
```

Se o link for de um profile pode validar com regex assim (neste exemplo aceita o `id` e a url com `profile`):

```
/^http://steamcommunity\.com/(id|profile)/([^/]+)$/.test(...)
```

Se for um link qualquer da steam pode validar assim:

```
/^http://steamcommunity\.com/([^/]+)$/.test(...)
```

No script adicione:

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#meuFormulario").validationEngine();
    });

    function checarLinkSteam(field, rules, i, options){

        //Valida se é um profile (o ! na frente é para negação, basico uso de IFs)
        if (!/^http://steamcommunity\.com/(id|profile)/([^/]+)$/.test(field.val())) {
            return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
```

Baseado nos exemplos: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/blob/master/demos/demoValidators.html

Answer (score 0):

Especificamente o campo ser um  link da steam não existe nada pronto que eu saiba, porém de começo você pode utilizar o  , para verificar especificamente se o usuário esta inputando um link , você pode posteriormente fazer um verificação da string digitada utilizando alguma função javascript, segue algumas soluções. [Como posso checar se uma string contém outra em Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3021/como-posso-checar-se-uma-string-cont%C3%A9m-outra-em-javascript)

Comment: O campo obrigatoriamente tem que ser o link assim:    http://steamcommunity.com/id/NeroParty/ ou assim http://steamcommunity.com/profile/417421894982