# Como Filtrar um array usando a estrutura For?

Tags: javascript, for, filter

como eu consigo filtrar um array usando a estrutura `for` ?

O código é esse:

```
const numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,55,190,355,747,1000,125];
```

> Preciso filtrar os numeros menores de 10.

Eu usei desta maneira, porém me pediram para eu criar um usando a estrutura `for` e eu não consigo sair do 0.

```js
const numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,55,190,355,747,1000,125];

const filterOne = x => x < 10;

const filterTwo = numeros.filter(filterOne);

console.log(filterTwo);
```

Comment: @ValdeirPsr 

Eu nem peguei para fazer, eu tava vendo uns exemplos pra ter uma noção mas não consigo entender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta fazer uma condição, também pode ser feito assim:

```
numeros.forEach((n) => {
  if (n < 10) {
    filterTwo.push(n);
  }
});
```

```js
const numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,55,190,355,747,1000,125];

const filterOne = x => x < 10;
const filterTwo = [];

for (let i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
  // Verifica que o valor de "numeros" no índice "i" é menor que 10
  if (numeros[i] < 10) {
    // adiciona no array filterTwo 
    filterTwo.push(numeros[i]);
  }
}

console.log(filterTwo);
```

#### Referência:

- [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
- [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Que ótimo, no caso se fosse palavras em vez de números.

Faria a mesma coisa?

Comment: Sim, mas a condição ficaria: `if (nomes[i] === 'Maria')`, caso o valor a ser verificado estivesse em uma variável `if (nomes[i] === nome)`.

Comment: Nossa cara, você é demais.

Agora ficou claro, e entendi como fazer. Mt obrigado Deus abençoe

Comment: Sou nada, apenas um aprendiz.

Comment: Uma ultima duvida, caso eu queria filtrar pelas letras.

Exemplo:
const nomes = ["jean", "souza", "wm", "marcelo"];

Filtrar todos os nomes que tenham a letra ''a'' como faria ?

Comment: Nessa pergunta: [**Como posso checar se uma string contém outra em Javascript?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3021/como-posso-checar-se-uma-string-cont%C3%A9m-outra-em-javascript) tem a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, rapidinho kk.

O que significa dizer esse código: numeros[i]

Que os elementos do numeros estão em i ?

Comment: [1,2,3,4,5,55,190,355,747,1000,125]
Quando coloca numeros[0],você está acessando a posição 0 do vetor,(no caso 1),numeros[6],você pega o valor 55,a variavel i está variando para percorrer o vetor,acessando a posição de cada 1.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar outra forma de laço, `forEach`, onde o parâmetro `(e)` representa o valor de cada item na array:

```js
const numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,55,190,355,747,1000,125];

const result = [];
numeros.forEach((e)=>{
   e < 10 && result.push(e);
});

console.log(result);
```

Explicação do [Short Circuit Operators](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_curto-circuito) usado no exemplo acima:

Retorna o segundo operando baseado no valor do primeiro. Se o primeiro for *false*, o segundo operando é ignorado.

```
e < 10 && result.push(e);
\____/  ↑ \____________/
 1º op. |     2º op.
        |
O 1º op. tem que ser true

e < 10 || result.push(e);
\____/  ↑ \____________/
 1º op. |     2º op.
        |
O 1º op. tem que ser false
```

Já os *Operadores Ternários* (*terno*, de 3) são formados por 3 operandos, separados por `?` (atende ao 1º op.) e `:` (não atende ao 1º op., similar ao `else`):

```
e < 10 ? faz uma coisa : faz outra coisa;
```

Comment: Qual o nome dado para esse verificação: `e < 10 && result.push(e);`? Primeira vez que vejo, sei que da pra fazer assim: `(e < 10): 'sim' ? 'não';`.. mas também não lembro o nome.

Comment: Esse é o _short circuit operators_: retorna o valor do segundo operando baseado no resultado do primeiro. Operador ternário é quando existem 3 operadores, como no seu exemplo acima.

Comment: Vendo as respostas da pergunta [**Como funciona este if/else com “?” e “:”?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907) e a documentação: [**Operadores Lógicos**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operadores_Logicos), ficou mais claro o funcionamento.

Comment: **dvd** o link [Short Circuit Operators](http://www.openjs.com/articles/syntax/short_circuit_operators.php) quebrou.